# Jquery change label text, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's the first time I try to code jquery and I can't change a bootstrap label text

I tried to code something, but it doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#customCheck1").on("change", checkboxChange);

    function checkboxChange()
    {
         $('#lblauto').val($("this").text());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto">Auto Reload OFF</label>
```

Comment: must be `$(this).text())`

Comment: I suggest you to use snippet as I did in order to ease the debugging. Otherwise, that was well done btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#lblauto').text("Checkbox is checked")
    } else {
        $('#lblauto').text("Checkbox is unChecked")
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto">Auto Reload OFF</label>
```

Comment: nope don't work :(, maybe i forgot to talk this string "<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" id="checkasd">" (This is the grup of the checkbox with the label)

Answer (score 1):

It's a label, it doesn't have a value property, use `.text()`:

```
$('#lblauto').text('Some Text');
```

Also, if using `this`, you don't wrap it in quotes:

`$(this)` or `this` is valid, `$("this")` is not

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#customCheck1").on("change", checkboxChange);

    function checkboxChange()
    {
         $('#lblauto').text("Checkbox changed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto">Auto Reload OFF</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I use `.html(this.value)` instead `$("this").text()` and secondly I added a value attribute to your checkbox such as below, and it works fine now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#customCheck1").on("change", checkboxChange);

  function checkboxChange() {
    $('#lblauto').html(this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" value="it works">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto">Auto Reload OFF</label>
```

See this code working on the website that you provided me.

[image]

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Add jQuery library `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">`, you can run the code to test it right in that window, and it works fine.

Comment: ....
            </script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Unfortunately, as it is working into the snippet and not on your side, it probably means that there is a piece of code that we are missing.

Comment: Include the jQuery library before the function, change text for html and it works, see the picture that I made from your website.

Comment: No problem! One last point. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.